# How to best temporarily support a load bearing wall with very weird sill plate

Tags: framing, structural

I'm moving walls in a 1923 home in the northwest, and things have been going well with temporary support walls while I construct new walls.  However, there's one bit I'm struggling with that I could use some help with.

In the attached pictures, the green markup/lines are where new studs and a 4x6 header are going, to span a 6.5' distance; the local building code office has signed off on it being compliant.

However, the vertical studs for the wall *above* this floor, for some reason were built extending below the 2nd story subfloor and landed on the sill plate marked in blue in the close up shot.
[image]

Those vertical studs do transfer some roof load, and an 8' wall of plaster and lath (heavy!), and they transfer down to subfloor between two 11" joists (spaced 6" apart). The studs are nailed into joist from the side with 2 nails apiece.

[image]
[image]
I intend to place a 4x6 beam under the sill plate marked in blue, but am trying to figure out how to temporarily brace the vertical studs for the wall above while I tear out the stuff marked in red in the wider pictures.  I'll be able to turn around the new framing in a day, so it's not a long time being unsupported, but I'm concerned about it keeping stable in the time it takes to demo and rebuild.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas. TYIA!